# ¿Cómo evitar números repetidos en un array en c#?

Tags: c#, array, numberformat

Estoy intentando crear un pequeño programa en `C#` que solicite 7 número y valide y evite que se repita un número del array(entero).

Este es mi código :

```
/*

24. Arreglos 2. Un programa que lea 7 valores enteros diferentes y los introduzca a un arreglo. (El programa debe validar que no se introduzca un número repetido). 

*/
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
           int[] arreglo = new int[7]; //creo el array
               int num;

           //Capturar arreglo 
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
                Console.Write ("Ingresa numero "); 

               string valor = Console.ReadLine();

               num = Convert.ToInt32(valor);

                if(num== arreglo[num]){
                 arreglo[num] = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine()); 
                }else{

                    Console.Write("es un numero repetido");
                }
            }}}//
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual es mi error?

Comment: Cada vez que insertes un numero.
Recorrer el arreglo y verificar si existe.

Comment: Te invito a que investiges los Contracts en C#. Es una forma de programar muy elegante que te ayudara a dar una solucion a este requerimiento.

Answer (score 7):

Otra opción que tienes, ya que quieres una colección de elementos que no se repitan,es usar una colección que específicamente no permita duplicados. En .Net disponemos de [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359438.aspx).

> La clase `HashSet<T>` proporciona operaciones de conjuntos de alto rendimiento. Un conjunto es una colección que no contiene ningún elemento duplicado y cuyos elementos se encuentran en ningún orden determinado.

El método `Add` de dicha colección devuelve un valor booleano que indica si el valor fué añadido o no. Usando esta `HashSet`, tu código podría ser algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
var hash = new HashSet<int>();
int num;
while (hash.Count<7)
{
    Console.Write("Ingresa numero ");
    string valor = Console.ReadLine();
    num = Convert.ToInt32(valor);
    if (!hash.Add(num))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("es un numero repetido");
    }
}
```

*Edit:* Veo que probablemente es un trabajo escolar y que seguramente debes usar arrays obligatoriamente. Pero dejaré mi respuesta por si le puede servir a algún otro usuario,

Comment: Correcto, HashSet es la forma mas eficiente que conozco de implementarlo en términos de performance.

Comment: @derloopkat lo es, pero la pregunta se basa en `arrays` , no.  cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Igual es una buena respuesta.

Comment: @Dev.Joel si, como pongo en la edición parece claro que es una tarea escolar que pide el uso de `arrays`,algo en lo que no me fijé al contestar. Pero creo que como puede ser útil para otros, no está de más dejar mi respuesta.

Comment: @Pikoh está genial .

Comment: Me sirvio el codigo!

Answer (score 6):

El código del for está correcta la idea de iterar 7 veces para solicitar 7 números diferentes , pero luego tienes errores muy puntuales .

1.-  `if(num== arreglo[num])` está preguntando si el número ingresado es igual a la posición num el cuál es incorrecto, ya que si ingresamos el número 13 por ejemplo,  estaremos accediendo a la posición 13 del array,pero este solo tiene 7, lo cuál daría un `IndexOutRangeException`.

2.- `arreglo[num] = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());` sucede lo mismo , pero ahora intenta almacenar el valor de la entrada en la posición del número ingresado lo cuál daría la exceptión anterior.

Teóricamente se podría realizar los siguietes pasos.

-Solicitar el número y luego iterar los elementos para saber si está o no lo está

```
int[] arreglo = new int[7]; //creo el array
int num;
// Variable Bandera
bool seEncuentra = false;
//Capturar arreglo 
for (int i = 0; i < 7;)
{
    //Inicializamos en noSeEncuentra
    seEncuentra = false;
    Console.Write("Ingresa numero ");
    //Obtenemos el número
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //Iteramos sobre el array para verificar que no se encuentre
    for(int j=0;j<arreglo.Length && !seEncuentra; j++)
    {
        // si es igual , se encuentra cambiamos la bandera
        if (arreglo[j] == num) seEncuentra = true;
    }
    //si se encuentra
    if (seEncuentra)
    {
        //regresamos y mostramos el mensaje respectivo
        Console.Write("Número Ingresado ya existe ");
    }
    else
    {
        //caso contrario añadimos el valor al array
        // e incrementamos el numero de eementos ingresados
        // i++ .
        arreglo[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Claro está que este for se puede simplificar y utilizar `contains` para verificar si el elemento existe en el array.

```
int[] arreglo = new int[7]; //creo el array
int num;
//Capturar arreglo sin incrementar el i ,
// seincrementará cuando encuentre un número no repetido
for (int i = 0; i < 7; )
{
    Console.Write("Ingresa numero ");

    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Verificamos si existe en el array
    if (!arreglo.Contains(num))
    {
        arreglo[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Es un numero repetido");
    }
}
```